# loop in loop ngrepeat angular js not working properly

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

im having some issues with Angular JS looping into data (ng repeat)

From php I send a multi assoc array back as json data. it holds resData and ResMenu each object holds data.

in my controller i have splitted this object in menu en resData. resdata works fine. But im having issues with res menu:

```
      $scope.resData = data.resData;
      $scope.resMenu = data.resMenu;
```

what i want is this:
I have categories => each category has some categorie data like name and then inside each category array there is a aray called "item" wich holds all the menu items that are connected to that category.

my repeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in resMenu">
  <div class="panel-heading menuHead">
    <h4 class="panel-title">{{cat.cat.maincatename}}
    </h4>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="item in resMenu" style="padding:5px !important">
  {{item.item.menu_name}}
  </a>
</div>
```

I see all the categories in the view with the names so that works. But now inside each category i want to show the menu items. But for some reason this does not work i also tried `item in resMenu.item` but for some reason i dont get the "loop in a loop" to work.

below i have pased te object from my console. Because it does not format well i have argumented it from "top down" to give a better understanding

JSON object (console)

```
Object {resMenu: Array[7], resData: Object}
resData: Object
resMenu: Array[7]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
length: 7
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

object in resMenu

```
0: Object
$$hashKey: "005"
cat: Object
item: Object
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
```

cat object looks like this

```
cat: Object
maincateid: "381"
maincatename: "Menu\'s compleet en voordelig"
restaurant_id: "70"
sortorder: "1"
status: "1"
```

item has nested objects again

```
item: Object
14: Object
20: Object
26: Object
32: Object
36: Object
39: Object
41: Object
43: Object
45: Object
47: Object
49: Object
51: Object
53: Object
55: Object
57: Object
```

and when i open a object i see the data..

Comment: why are you looping over same array in the nested `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change inner ng-repeat

```
<a href="" class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="item in cat.item" style="padding:5px !important">
  {{item.menu_name}}
</a>
```